# Prblem in Deserialization of JSON

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

My project gets a lot of JSON strings via UDP, each string describing some list of objects.
I could'nt write a function that get a some list, and make Derialization to this list.
The problem is that I can not make Derialization without knowing the class name of the objects that make up the list.
I tried to give each department ID field .. But here, too, I could not do Derialization for specific field, because where the department name is not known.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Include at **least** an example of the JSON input that causes the problem and **ideally** your code attempting to deserialize it.

Comment: Do you have chance to influence the data coming to you?

Answer (score 2):

Make all your entities get implemented from Base class:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
     public EntityTypeEnum EntityType {get;set;}
}

public enum EntityTypeEnum 
{
   EntityOne,
   EntityTwo,
   EntityThree
}
```

Now you can deserialize at the begining your entity from JSON to BaseEntity, look what kind of entity you get end then deserialize to the type which you get.

```
  JsonSerializer js = new JsonSerializer();
  var baseEntity = js.Deserialize<BaseEntity>()
  switch(baseEntity.EntityType)
  {
      case EntityOne:
         var result= js.Deserialize<EntityOne>();
         //DoSomeThing
      break; 
      case EntityTwo:
         var result= js.Deserialize<EntityTwo>();
         //DoSomeThing
      break; 
  }
```

**EDIT for `Zoka`**

If you want to implement anything else by your entity you can do like this:

```
public class AnythingElse : BaseEntity
{
     //...
}

public class EntityFour : AnythingElse
{
   //....
}
```

**EDIT №2 for Zoka**

If you need your DTOs to be implemented from any other 3rd party library class just do like this:

```
public abstract class BaseEntity : AnyOther3rdPartyLibraryClass
{
    public EntityTypeEnum EntityType {get;set;}
}

public class EntityFive : BaseEntity
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Just to be precise - this solution is better than mine (therefore +1), but is useless in case you cannot inherit your data from anything else. Then, my solution is better - non-intrusive.

Comment: Actualy you can inherit. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Maybe you cannot. What if you need send over `class X` from 3rd party DLL?

Comment: I knew that it will be your argument. ) Yes, you are right the `op` will have the issue if his DTOs have to be inherited from 3rd party DLL classes. But only if he need to do it. But there is one more solution for this situation - BaseEntity can implement the 3rd party dll class.

Comment: You are totally intrusive with your intrusive version... (just joke).
OK, it is solution, but for example sometimes I prefer not to messup my classes with non-related code. Therefore I offered my solution. But as I said firstly - your solution is better and I mean it.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the JSON problem.
I would go the way of encapsulation.
Firstly I would create the wrapper:

```
public class JSONObjectWrapper
{
    public string ObjectType;
    public string ObjectInJSON;
    [DoNotSerialize] // sorry do not remember the attribute to exclude it from serialization
    public object ObjectData;
}
```

During serialization you will explicitly serialize `ObjectData` into `ObjectInJSON`. And then send the serialized JSONOBjectWrapper.

On the incoming side you always know it is JSONObjectWrapper. Deserialize it - by this you get the JSON with the object and object type. Find this object type, create it using some factory and then deserialize it from `OBjectInJSON` into `ObjectData`.

The procedure above will work only if you may do the wrapping on the transmitting side. Otherwise, you are screwed :-)

Comment: I chose this solution.. tnx!